# How to validate in Mongoose an array and the same time its elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this schema where I validated the elements of array `book`, but I don't know how to validate the array itself.

```
 var DictionarySchema = new Schema({   
        book: [
            {              
                1: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                2: String,
                3: String,
                c: String,
                p: String,
                r: String
            }
        ]
    });
```

For example, I would like to put the book array as required. Any help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [custom validator](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) to do this. Simply check that the array itself is not empty:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var bookSchema = new Schema({

  1: { type: String, required: true },
  2: String,
  3: String,
  c: String,
  p: String,
  r: String
});

var dictSchema = new Schema({
  books: [bookSchema]
});

dictSchema.path('books').validate(function(value) {
  return value.length;
},"'books' cannot be an empty array");

var Dictionary = mongoose.model( 'Dictionary', dictSchema );


var dict = new Dictionary({ "books": [] });


dict.save(function(err,doc) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(doc);

});
```

Which will throw an error when there is no content in the array, and otherwise pass off the validation for the rules supplied for the fields in the array.

Comment: Thanks, that was very useful!!!. But, there is another way to pass validation to the array `book` inline. Because sometimes will be necessary to use other differents filters to `required` such as (`max`, `min`, `expires`, `enum`, `lowercase`, `match`, `trim`, `uppercase`, etc) which are already provided by mongoose, and I think this may be inefficient to implement it in a `validate()` function.

Comment: @in3pi2 This is how the validation is performed for all the built in types and rules under the hood anyway, and the mongoose API just exposes the internal method so you can "plug-in" to it. Also see [plugins](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/plugins.html) from the documentation.

Comment: @in3pi2 Because mongoose does that by default. You can turn it off though. Read through the documentation and if you have other question then ask another question rather than post comments.