# How do I validated array of objects using mongodb validator?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have been trying to validate my data using the validators provided by MongoDB but I have run into a problem. Here is a simple user document which I am inserting.

```
{
    "name"    : "foo",
    "surname" : "bar",
    "books"   : [
      {
        "name" : "ABC",
        "no"   : 19
      },
      {
        "name" : "DEF",
        "no"   : 64
      },
      {
        "name" : "GHI",
        "no" : 245
      }
    ]
}
```

Now, this is the validator which has been applied for the user collection. But this is now working for the books array which I am inserting along with the document. I want to check the elements inside the object which are the members of books array. The schema of the object won't change.

```
db.runCommand({
  collMod: "users",
  validator: {
    $or : [
      { "name"       : { $type : "string" }},
      { "surname"    : { $type : "string" }},
      { "books.name" : { $type : "string" }},
      { "books.no"   : { $type : "number" }}
    ],
  validationLevel: "strict"
});
```

I know that this validator is for member objects and not for array, but then how do I validate such an object ?

Comment: I think this link will provide you the solution->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965535/how-to-validate-in-mongoose-an-array-and-the-same-time-its-elements

Comment: Hey @RiyaSaxena ... No that doesn't work with with mongodb .. thanks anyways

Comment: did you ever find out how to validate `array` type?

Comment: It cannot be done. Not currently, maybe in future versions they'll give us that option.

Answer (score 16):

It has been very long since this question was asked.
Anyways, if at all anyone comes through this.

For **MongoDB 3.6** and greater version, this can be achieved using the validator.

```js
 db.createCollection("users", {
    validator: {
       $jsonSchema: {
          bsonType: "object",
          required: ["name","surname","books"],
          properties: {
            name: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be a string and is required"
             },    
             surname: {
                bsonType: "string",
                description: "must be a string and is required"
             },         
             books: {
                bsonType: [ "array" ],
                items: {
                    bsonType: "object",
                    required:["name","no"],
                    properties:{
                        name:{
                            bsonType: "string",
                            description: "must be a string and is required"
                        },
                        no:{
                            bsonType: "number",
                            description: "must be a number and is required"
                        }
                    }
                },
                description: "must be a array of objects containing name and no"
             }
          }
       }
    }
 })
```

This one handles all your requirements.
**For more information, refer this [link](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-36-json-schema-validation-expressive-query-syntax)**

Comment: funny how i wanted to post exactly this answer and you already did it in the same hour - even though are more then 2 years since this question was posted :)) very clear answer, thanks :)

Comment: Why does `books` have `bsonType: [ "array" ]` and not `bsonType: "array"`? Typo?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 3.6 using [$jsonSchema](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/index.html) expression.

JsonSchema allows defining a [field as an array](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.4) and specifying schema constraints for all elements as well as specific constraints for individual array elements.

[This blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-36-json-schema-validation-expressive-query-syntax) has a number of examples which will help you figure out the syntax.