# MongoDB - how to have variable structure for an object within a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to store key data for various types of documents(company documents, not Mongo document) in a collection. The fields of the collection need to be as follows

```
_id (ofcourse);
docName: string;
docDate: Date;
docShName: string;
docData: { a variable nested object };
```

This docData object will be different for each type of docName. i.e. it will store different fields.

e.g.
docName could be Board Meeting Notice, Reporting Calendar, AGM Meeting, etc.

There will be a data model for each of the above type of doc.

So the docData
for Board Meeting could be
`{ a: string, b: string , c: string[] }`

for AGM could be
`{ p: string [], q: string, x: string, y: Date, z: Boolean }`

Is it possible to have such a collection?
If yes, then how do I define the docData in the model for the collection in Node backend?

If No, then I need to create separate collections for Board Metting, AGM, etc. Any workaround for having a central Collection of all documents?

Comment: i think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504658/how-do-i-validated-array-of-objects-using-mongodb-validator

Comment: Saw that thread. So are you saying that the data model for the collection should have all possible fields and not mark them as required -except the common fields,  docName, docDate, docShName.

Comment: my approach would be to do a 'oneof' where the common fields are always required and the other fields are required conditionally

Comment: i think that would have performance implications as well, depending on how write heavy the use case is.

Comment: but you may add more fields like this in the future and not want to add new collections, so thats the other side of that trade off. i would say do it, because your use case maps fairly cleanly to https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#oneof