# Not able to Insert a record in Collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodb-query, schema, mongo-shell

I have been trying to validate the schema in MongoDB but encountering an error.
I have tried Restarting the server,
Dumping the collection,
creating a new collection with the validation,
created a new name collection with the same validation but it is still not working.

**Collection Schema:**

```js
db.createCollection("fiction", {
    validator: {
        required: ['name', 'price', 'authors'], 
        properties: {
            name: {
                bsonType: 'string',
                description: 'must be a String and required'
            },
            price: {
                bsonType: 'number',
                description: 'must be a number and required'
            },
            authors: {
                bsonType: 'array',
                description: 'must be an array and required', 
                items: {
                    bsonType: 'object',
                    properties: {
                        name: {
                            bsonType: 'string'
                        },
                        email: {
                            bsonType: 'string'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    validationAction: 'error'
})
```

**Inserting Data with this:**

```js
db.nonfiction.insertOne({
    name : "Cant hurt ME",
    price:400.20,
    authors:[
        {
            name:"David",
            email:"admin@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            name:"Smith",
            email:"admin@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
})
```

I tried dropping the collection.

Recreating the Schema from all over again.

checked the Typo as well.
used chatGPT as well.

Mongo version :  7.0.0
os : ubuntu 22.04 LTS
shell :  Mongosh

THis is the error msg I am getting when inputting data.

```js
lib> db.fiction.insertOne({
...     name: "Sample Fiction Book",
...     price: 19.99,
...     authors: [
...         {
...             name: "Author Name",
...             email: "author@email.com"
...         },
...         {
...             name: "Co-Author Name",
...             email: "coauthor@email.com"
...         }
...     ]
... })
Uncaught:
MongoServerError: Document failed validation
Additional information: {
  failingDocumentId: ObjectId("64f719e6f13ccec17a71558e"),
  details: {
    operatorName: '$and',
    clausesNotSatisfied: [
      {
        index: 0,
        details: {
          operatorName: '$eq',
          specifiedAs: { required: [ 'name', 'price', 'authors' ] },
          reason: 'field was missing'
        }
      },
      {
        index: 1,
        details: {
          operatorName: '$eq',
          specifiedAs: {
            properties: { name: [Object], price: [Object], authors: [Object] }
          },
          reason: 'field was missing'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What's happening when you try?

Comment: I Have edited the {ost with the Error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I validated array of objects using mongodb validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504658/how-do-i-validated-array-of-objects-using-mongodb-validator)